# Symfony4 form handleRequest not submitting request data

Tags: forms, symfony4

When i submit a json http post request in symfony4 the requesthandling not submitting my form.

I tried setting the "method" option to the form to post, but it doesn't seem to help. I'm using the application/json header for Content-type and Accept.

The form:

```php
class SecurityUserForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => SecurityUser::class,
                'csrf_protection' => false,
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

The controller:

```php
    public function postAction(Request $request,  SerializerInterface $serializer, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        try {
            $user = new SecurityUser();
            $form = $this->createForm(SecurityUserForm::class, $user,
                array(
                    'method' => 'POST'
                ));
            $form->handleRequest($request); //NOT SUBMITTING THE FORM
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                dump("submitted");
            } else {
                //Stuff
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //Exception handling stuff
        }
    }
```

And my http post:

Headers:
  Content-Type:application/json
  Accept:application/json

Body:
{
    "username": "dunglas"
}

I expect the $form->handleRequest($request) to submit the form, but for some reason it doesn't. When i dump after handling the request

```php
dump($form->isSubmitted()) //false
```

it returns false.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The form gets submitted from the front end, either by standard http request (clicking a submit button) or with a javascript ajax call please share that code

Comment: I'm using postman, and i submitting the form properly

Answer (score 0):

You need change `$form->handleRequest($request);` to `$form->submit($request->request->all());`